# Site comes up Sometime and Sometimes it will not

Tags: wordpress, url, dns, web

I have a site registered with Godaddy and hosting with Enom.  The domain was pointed to Enom's nameservers on 1/14/15 and was fine until 1/17/15.  It's a wordpress site and on 1/17/15, without doing anything to it, it went down and I could not access it via FTP either.  It was literally down all day.  The strange thing is, it seemed to be accessible on cellphones, but not PCs.  On 1/18/15 I was able to access it via FTP & via all browsers.

On 1/18 it went down again and suddenly came back up.  (I checked at 6pm and it was back up and running fine.)  Checked 1/19 and all is good again.

When I was unable to access the site via FTP (Filezilla), I got the following error: "connection attempt failed with eai_nodata - no address associated with codename"

When I tried on all browsers, I received a DNS lookup failed.

This is the strangest thing I have encountered.  Does anyone have any idea if this is a problem coming from the Registar or the hosting company?  Any suggestions or ideas are welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

your phone is on Wi-Fi of same network as your PC or on mobile phone network?

If on a different network so check if it happens only in your computer or in other computers to (You could check with proxy sites ,hidemyass for example).

If its only on your PC, sounds like its a problem with your internet provider with the DNS/IP of your server.

I had the same issue, one time after a few days it solved itself. In some other case i had, it was something in the internet provider actually (the DNS was blocked or something or not updated or something like that).

The reason it sounds like that is because in your phone your site is up, but could be its something else.

Comment: Thank batz.  I forgot to mention that I checked it on more than one computer.  I had two other people in different locations test when it was coming up it and it failed for them as well.

Comment: So only in your phone the is up? What about now, the site is up? Is is it still down?